# MonkeyTalk Android Detect String Containing \n for Button Tap

Tags: android, button, special-characters, monkeytalk

I am using MonkeyTalk to automate some user test cases for my Android app. Everything is working fine except for when I try and detect a button containing this string:

```
"Connect\n(Code Required)"
```

I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Unable to find Button(Connect\n(Code required))
```

If I change the button to "Connect" and perform a tap on that value MonkeyTalk has no trouble, but something about the line break must be throwing it off.

After some searching I found [this thread](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/content/monkeytalk-not-able-play-back-steps-buttons-have-text-n-them) that confirmed my suspicious about the line break. There was one suggested fix here, to set the default encoding to UTF-8 (Select the Project > File > Properties > Resources)

However this did not work for me.

I have also tried to find the button using a wildcard like so:

```
"*(Code Required)"
```

But this does not seem to be supported either.

Maybe there is an alternative line break character I could use?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried escaping it with `\\n`?

Comment: I like where your head's at, but still getting same error :/

Comment: Ithink you have to try this way yourButton.setText(Html.fromHtml("Connect</br>(Code Required)"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a carriage return in there? I know in most text editors a new line actually consists of (carriage return)+(newline).

Also take a look at this: 
[TextView carriage return not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455194/textview-carriage-return-not-working)

Also, depending on how flexible your requirements are, you could use the #N MonkeyId replacement to get the Nth button.

Answer (score 0):

IN javascript you can use below command

```
app.button("buttonname").tap(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:contentDesxription="your_component_id"` in your view xml file definition or `view.setContentDescription("your_component_id");` directly on view in code to make it easy to access in MonkeyTalk.